# jQuery and iframes and weird positioning: is there a workaround?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, iframe, jquery-ui-draggable

I've got a draggable thing outside an iframe, and a droppable target inside it. Here I've shown the iframe as containing a snippet of the HTML that is loaded by its src attribute.

```
<div id="draggables">
  <img src="drag-me.gif">
</div>

<iframe src="iframe-src.html" id="iframe">
  <!-- HTML gubbins -->

  <div id="droppable">&nbsp;</div>

  <!-- More HTML gubbins -->
</iframe>
```

I use some jQuery (UI draggable/droppable) to do stuff:

```
$("#iframe").load(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var contents = $this.contents();

    contents.find('#droppable').droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) { alert('dropped'); }
    });
    $('#draggables img').draggable();
});
```

The draggables become draggable and the droppable is successfully a drop target. The problem is that the landing zone for the drop area is not where it is displayed on the screen. That is, the alert is fired when the draggable is dropped somewhere above the drop target, and not on the target itself.

A few tests I did suggest that the difference between where the target is on screen and where jQuery thinks it is is related to the vertical position of the iframe on the page, but I can't find a direct correlation. Does anyone know whether this problem has been investigated by anyone anywhere and, perchance, solved?

Failing that, can anyone suggest a way I may be able to load an external HTML file into my page without using an iframe and without the two pages' structures and styles interfering with one another? I'm considering loading the inner page directly and using javascript to draw page controls around it.

TIA
Altreus

Comment: I am facing the same problem !! let me know if u succeed

Comment: Found this searching for answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36368327/dropping-a-draggable-div-into-sortable-table-which-is-inside-the-iframe-and-on-d Looks like the Offset might be the key yet not seen an update to the scroll portion via GIST below.

Comment: After a bit of trial and error, my wacky-hacky solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52317620/3175487 it was good enough for what I needed, but it is not a real fix for the problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access the parent element from within the child iframe.  I haven't personally tested it, but try to set context for your jquery selector.  Otherwise, it'll look only inside the current iFrame.

```
$('#draggables img', parent).draggable();
```

Comment: Question going into three years now, but just in case, this seems to work for me: `$('#draggables img', window.top.document)`

Answer (score 0):

It was asked a long ago, but digging SO I found a GIST where people solved this problem by overwriting the default behavior of `$.ui.ddmanager.prepareOffsets`.

You can find the working code here:
https://gist.github.com/gujiman/581a3cee1dbf4beafccb