# JQuery draggable outside iframe. Droppable inside iframe

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, iframe, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a jquery draggable outside of an iframe.  I need to make elements within the iframe droppables.  When I drag over the iframe, the "over" event doesn't fire but if I continue to drag above the iframe, the "over" event does fire.

It looks like this was also posted here but never answered.
[jQuery and iframes and weird positioning: is there a workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491981/jquery-and-iframes-and-weird-positioning-is-there-a-workaround)

Edit: Code example

html

```
<div id="draggable">
</div>

<iframe id="iframe"/>
```

javascript

```
$("#draggable").draggable();

var body = $('#iframe').contents().find('body');
$(body).droppable({
    over:function(event,ui) {
        alert('over droppable');
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you show us a bit of code perhaps?

Comment: I have the same problem!  Any leads on a solution?

Comment: Seems like the bizarre way the positioning works on the iframe makes this complicated, the reason it's doing it above the iframe is because it's taking the positioning from the top left of the screen and not the iframe or so I assume.

Comment: Incidentally, your iframe shoulde be `<iframe></iframe>` as it's not a self closing tag

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use like this code.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div style="width:400px; height:200px; overflow:auto">
<iframe src="iframe.html" style="width:400px; height:400px;"></iframe>
</div>
<div  style="width:60px; height:60px; background-color: #808080" id="drag"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript

```
$(function () {
        $("iframe").load(function () {
            var iframe = $(this).contents();
            iframe.find('#iframe_container').droppable(
            {
                iframeFix: true,
                drop: function (event, ui) { alert('dropped'); }
            });
        });
        $('#drag').draggable({iframeFix: true});
    });
```