# Dropping a draggable div into sortable table which is inside the iframe and on drop (stop) replace that div with table-row

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a page with list of draggable elements and an iframe with sortable table in which all TRs are sortable.
And I want to drag the draggable elements (which are out side the iframe ) into iframe's sortable table and on drop complete the div should be replaced by TR.

Now every thing seems ok but when I drop draggable into sortable there a lot delay in replacing the div with TR. ( Browser is not freezing )

What would be reason ? Am I doing the correct way ?

Thanks for answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20934249/drag-and-connecttosortable-into-sortable-div-inside-the-iframe?s=0|1.2187.    Similar question did not answered.

Comment: So you're using draggable to indicate that you wish to add or replace an element in another page's DOM through an iFrame and you're wondering why it's taking time? How long is it taking? Did you setup a counter to time the start and end of these events? Console details? Is there any AJAX at play here?

Comment: How about some code or example so we can see if anything there can be optimized?

Comment: I made a quick example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/2n0kz9x4/ It's not slow, yet it is working in a weird way.

Comment: @Twisty, Yes I am doing the same and using ajax.

Comment: Twisty , Thanks for putting fiddle. This exactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: I Updated the Fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/2n0kz9x4/2/ . I removed ajax functionality but still it is behaving weird.

Comment: I wonder if the use of the `table` in the source is creating this large offset. Investigating.

Comment: I think this is partly due to generating the content of the iFrame dynamically. Trying to find a workspace where I can create a html file to be the source of the iFrame - found some good examples: http://jqfaq.com/how-to-implement-drag-and-drop-between-iframes/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491981/jquery-and-iframes-and-weird-positioning-is-there-a-workaround/15091193#15091193

Comment: @Twisty, 

Thanks for Links.

If I use div instead of Iframe everything works fine. But I need an iframe. The reason is I do not want to inherit CSS from the page. It should have its own CSS context. 
The Replacing content is from the same domain too (localhost).

Comment: In the first link, They used droppable. I am using sortable. I need to check that. May be replacing content causing the ambiguity.

Comment: It's all very related to the offsets. That is more confirmed by your using a div vs iframe. Not sure why you're using the iframe in your project.

Comment: @Twisty Thanks for reply. I am loading Email template in the iframe so that the CSS will not be inherited from Parent document (As I commented above). The element with sortable (My case TBODY) is causing the problem. Dragging on TABLE is fine. I am trying different ways.

Comment: I fixed to some extent but not fully.  Still trying .. https://jsfiddle.net/2n0kz9x4/5/

Comment: Dragging from top is causing vertical offset and from left giving horizontal offset.  https://jsfiddle.net/2n0kz9x4/6/

Comment: Hello @Twisty, I figured out Services like mailChimp, Campaign monitor uses an editor in the same way I am trying to build.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for twisty for trying out.

After an extensive research I figured out the problem is with latest jquery-ui plugin. If I use the version 1.9.2 the problem is getting solved.

So, If anyone facing the same problem. Just change the version to 1.9.2 not less not more just the same.

I raised this issue at jquery website. All these kind of issues are referenced to [#7925](https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7925).

they are just saying:

> We don't support cross-window dragging.

Comment: The solution referenced in #7925 actually works pretty well.  It' is not perfect, but I implemented it anyway as described https://stackoverflow.com/a/52317620/3175487  and it worked well enough for what I needed.